# More on Ambiguous Diminutives

Tags: dialect, bavarian, yiddish, diminutive

There is an interesting discussion going on about the word for rabbit, *Kaninchen* which looks like a diminutive but (probably) isn't. The question arose in [that thread](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23711/more-pseudo-diminutives-like-eichh%C3%B6rnchen) over whether there are other examples of words which are problematic in this way: e.g. how do you have a [“little rabbit”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13462/how-do-you-say-small-rabbit-in-german)?

Of course in Yiddish it’s not a problem because we have the **double diminutive** *+ele*. I’m wondering if they have the same in the dialects e.g. Bavarian where they use the same *+el* ending for diminutives. An interesting situation arises when a normal word ending in *-el* looks the same as another word that is a diminutive. For example, a little goat (*Ziegel*) looks like a normal-size brick (*Ziegel*). It almost even looks like a small train (*Zügel*) – actually, in Yiddish the correspondence is exact because the U-umlaut is not distinguished from long-i (*ie*).

And does it sound funny in Bavarian to call a big bird like an Ostrich a *Vögel*? Does anyone hyper-correct this to *ein Vog*?

In Yiddish, noodles are *lokshin*, as in *lockshin kugel*. But I’ve never figured out where this comes from. I have a theory that it’s actually *Lockchen/Löckchen* (little curls).  Of course, the Yiddish plural diminutive would be *Löckellach*. Any ideas?

Comment: Just some minor corrections: (1) it's a "Vogel" (plural: "Vögel"), (2) "Löckchen" (both singular and plural, the diminutive for "Locken"), (3) "Zügel" means "rein" and isn't a diminutive for "Zug"; a small train would be a "Züglein".

Comment: Regarding the diminutive for "Zug" in Bavaria, I'm only aware of "Zügerl". I've never heard "Zügel".

Comment: oh dear yes of course you're right about Vogel...but then is the diminutive the same as the plural (in Bavarian)?

Comment: @MartyGreen There is no such thing as a standard diminutive -el in Bavarian (I am from Bavaria). Bavarians tend to end nouns with -erl, which is the dialect form of "-chen" or "-lein". For example, there's "Häuserl" (Häuschen) or "Vögerl" (Vögelchen) or "Zügerl" (Züglein). Like -le in Schwaben: "Häusle", "Vögele", "Zügle".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Although I don’t quite get what the OP’s question really is, you should probably elaborate a bit and promote your comment to an answer. If you do so, please also cover cases like _Hendl_ and _Dirndl_.

Comment: The above comment about lokshen makes sense. It is said in the Merriam-Webster "lokshen Yiddish (plural of loksh noodle), from Russian dialect loksha". As a person speaking and knowing Russian as a native speaker, I say that the Russian word for noodle is "lapsha", which perhaps got transferred to "loksha" somehow

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a standard diminutive *-el* in Bavarian. Even though I'm from Bavaria I'm not an expert in *all* Bavarian dialects. However, in the Bavarian dialect you usually hear in the Regensburg area, the endings *-chen* and *-lein* are replaced by *-erl*.

Examples:

```
Häuserl (Häuschen)
Vogerl (Vögelchen)
Zügerl (Züglein)
```

As there are many Bavarian dialects (sometimes strongly varying even between villages) there are further shortened forms (for example in Munich) like *Hendl*, *Dirndl*, *Madl* which of course derive from the long form *Henderl*, *Dirnderl* or *Maderl*, which are also in use.

In the Franconian area around Nürnberg for example, *-lä* is common:

```
Häuslä
Vöglä
Züglä
Madlä
```

> And does it sound funny in Bavarian to call a big bird like an Ostrich a Vögel? Does anyone hyper-correct this to ein Vog?

First of all, an Ostrich would be called *Vogel*, not *Vögel*, as *Vögel* is the plural. It would sound funny if you called it *Vögelchen*/*Vogerl*, but people sometimes do this intentionally to make a joke:

```
Ein Strauß ist definitiv mal ein flottes Vögelchen.
```

There is no such thing as a *Vog* in German. The word is *Vogel*, so no, nobody calls an Ostrich *Vog*. As *Vogel* in German is not a diminutive form, it would rather not be understood.

Comment: Im Atlas zur Deutschen Gegenwartssprache gibt es zu diesem Thema leider nur eine relativ unübersichtliche monochrome [Karte zu _Häuschen_](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Haeuschen.jpg) sowie bunte zum [_(Grill-)Hähnchen_](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/9_01b/) und Plural von [_Mädchen_](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f5e-2/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about dialects but in standard German, a small rabbit would be *das kleine Kaninchen*. Same goes for *das kleine Mädchen* etc. The German Wikipedia article on diminutives has a [section](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutiv#Verselbst.C3.A4ndigte_Diminutive) that lists just the examples you are talking about.

As for *lokshen*, [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lokshen) lists the origin as Russian but I don't know enough about Russian grammar to say if it's a diminutive or not. :)